# Exporting SSRS Report with nested Drill Through

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to export a report which has a drill through. I have some reports which I need to export to PDF, including all drill throughs?

The main report drills through about 4-5 times and I need a PDF for each of those?

- Faculty
- Division
- approx. 20 Courses
- Course Information

Can I export a PDF which gets all the information?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that I can think of for this is to create subscriptions that produce the report based on pre-specified parameters. For example if your report has 2 levels (Top, Bottom)

You would have two subscriptions and specify one to produce the pdf for top and one for bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If We export an SSRS report to pdf, it gets exported as such. if you have a drill down, and you exported it to pdf, with drill-down part visible, then it will also be visible in export.
In drill down mechanism is not available in pdf.

Export to excel, if you want drill down facility in sub report.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2